# Qrartz.net DailyTimeIntervalScheduleBuilder - How to identity first and last execution of the trigger in a day

Tags: quartz.net-3.0

Trying to Identity the first and last execution of a trigger in a day when `quartz.net` fire `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)`. Is there any way to to find this in `quartz.net` `Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<DateTime> firingTimes = context.Trigger.GetNextFiringTimes(DateTimeOffset.Now.Date, DateTimeOffset.Now.Date.AddDays(1));

public static class TriggerExts
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> GetNextFiringTimes(this ITrigger trigger, DateTimeOffset? after = null, DateTimeOffset? before = null)
    {
        ITrigger temp = trigger.Clone();

        after = after ?? DateTimeOffset.Now;
        DateTimeOffset? next = temp.GetFireTimeAfter(after);
        before = before ?? next.Value.AddYears(1);

        while (next.HasValue && next.Value < before)
        {
            yield return next.Value.LocalDateTime;

            next = temp.GetFireTimeAfter(next.Value);
        }
    }
}
```